# PostgreSQL: INSERTING a record into a child table when the parent table already exists

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, single-table-inheritance

I have two tables where there is a record on the parent table where I want to create a child record that builds on the record. The detail of what I did is below:

Having two tables created with a serial PK.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.parent
(
    parent_id smallserial NOT NULL,
    parent_field character varying(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (parent_id)
)


CREATE TABLE public.child
(
    child_id smallserial,
    child_field character varying(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (child_id)
)
    INHERITS (public.parent);
```

And then carrying out a:

```
INSERT INTO parent (parent_field) VALUES ('Hello World');
```

The ID the sequence gave was 4. I then tried running this query to build on that field on the child table:

```
INSERT INTO child (parent_id, parent_field, child_field)
VALUES (4, 'Hello World', 'The child');
```

But I ended up with two records on the parent table:
[image]

If I only want to have one parent record with that PK, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to use table inheritance for this? It works correctly, but I don't think this is what you want. "parent" is your main table and all records in this table AND all records in table "child" will be selected. On top of that there are some details just for the "child" records. You might want to take a look at a structure like this: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-recursive-query/

Comment: Essentially, I am building a database where I use the "parent" table to store data on business transactions that are not yet approved. When a transaction is approved I wanted to move it to the "child" table. I initially used a foreign key to connect my two tables but I am just exploring if this is possibly done through inheritance.

Comment: That means that a single transaction can have multiple statuses. No need for moving data around, just create a table with an id for the transaction, a timestamp and a status. Latest timestamp for a certain transaction shows you the current status for this transaction.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but how would you go about it when an approved transaction comes with additional fields? Say an unapproved transaction is only composed of 5 fields. But when it is approved, additional 5 fields needs to be filled up for it.

Comment: Leave them empty when empty and update them later. Or create an additional table with these details and an id for the transaction. But try to keep it as simple as possible.